# Can TeamCity completely replace all custom build scenarios?

Tags: python, teamcity

I am managing a build for a cross platform project: OSX/Windows/Linux. I simply run a Makefile with command: `make win_installer`, `make linux` and `make mac`.

Respectively for each Operating system.

For this, in the server I run a Python Twisted application that will monitor regularly if there is new tag in our git repository. If detected, a build will commence and the resulting artefacts will be uploaded into our private FTP.

Can TeamCity be easily configured to implement this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there are 3 basic steps(you can have one teamcity agent on each of the OS and run individual targets for OS specific build  in specific agent)

1. Setup a teamcity target to run whenever there are changes to a tag
   https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers#ConfiguringVCSTriggers-BranchFilter
2. Add a comand line build step for the makefile
3. Add a command line target to upload the makefile to your artefact repository

Comment: Interesting. It really is supplying the same feature as our current custom CI solution built using Python. Thanks for pointing me to the right doc. I'll accept this as my answer of choice! :)

Comment: Yes, you can do a lot of stuff that teamcity does in any custom script. But they have a very well tested and robust code,I have never found bugs in their implementations, and impressive features are added every release

Comment: Agree. Making my own CI like solution, may solved temporary problem. But it may break in the future when new things reveal!